# How do I calculate the current needed to prevent corrosion on a piece of metal?

Tags: electrolysis

Consider I have a piece of aluminum and a caustic bath of some Ph level. If I stick the aluminum in the bath, it will corrode over time depending on the Ph level of the solution.

I understand it is possible to prevent corrosion by applying current through the metal. If the bath is the electrolyte what is anode? Can the aluminum be both, or must it require a sacrificial piece of metal?

Also, is it possible to take some electrical measurements of the solution to determine how much current is required to flow through the cathode to prevent corrosion?

Comment: I think you'd better ask the first question on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ Regarding measuring currents, look for "current sense resistor" and in case of large currents, search on "Kelvin connection" as well.

Comment: It's actually a voltage, not a specific current that is required to minimize corrosion.